# Basic question about updating local.xml

Tags: magento

I have a basic question that which way of updating is good in **local.xml** or in every **.xml** files separately. I observed that for each update i have to go to my **.xml** files in **base** then copying tags then edit.
I already did a project editing **.xml** files separately from my local package/theme. It looks easy to me.
I want your suggestions as i am **newbie**

I followed the link for better way of layout update from local.xml as well:
http://classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros and cons of local.xml explained here http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/using-local-xml-for-overriding-or-updating-xml-structure/